# How to implement either tagging or build in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I add a choice parameter in jenkins job, as follows:
[image]

I'm trying to do builds or tags through a pipeline script that.

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'docker-slave2' }

    stages {

        stage('addtag') {
            when {
                expression { params.TAG_OR_BUILD == 'ADDTAG' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "$params.TAG_OR_BUILD"
                }
        }
        
        stage('build') {
            
        }
        
        stage('upload')
        
    }
}
```

The first STAGE of the pipeline above is for TAG, the second and third STAGE are the BUILD steps.

Now I want to execute only the first stage of the pipeline when I select **ADDTAG** in the choice parameter and only the second and third stage of the pipeline when I select **BUILD** in the choice parameter, how can I modify the above pipeline to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define parameters before starting the stages under agent, like

```html
pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker-slave2' }
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'TAG_OR_BUILD', choices: ['ADDTAG', 'BUILD'], description: 'Select TAG or BUILD')
    }
    stages {
        stage('ADDTAG') {
            when {
                expression { params.TAG_OR_BUILD == 'ADDTAG' }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Perform steps for TAG'
                // Add the steps for tagging here
            }
        }
    stage('BUILD') {
        when {
            expression { params.TAG_OR_BUILD == 'BUILD' }
        }
        steps {
            echo 'Perform BUILD'
            // Add the steps for building here
        }
    }
}
}
```

Make Sure You define the same parameters as it is case sensitives.